# Передача значения переменной Ajax запросом на сервер?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlet, xmlhttprequest

Не правильно передаю значение переменной на сервер, сервер в консоли null, где моя ошибка?

**Javascript в index.jsp**

```
<script>
var name="45";
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "Server", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(name);
}
</script>
```

**Сервлет**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные отправляются в форме наборa пар - `ключ=значение`:

```
xhttp.send("name=" + name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй форм дата , это куда проще.
В JS
    `var data = new FormData();`
    `data.append('Ключ', значение);`
    `xhttp.sen(data);`
Можно добавлять сколько угодно ключей и значений. И просто обращаешься по ключу.

```
    `String name = req.getParameter("Ключ");`
```

Comment: data.append('Ключ1', значение1);data.append('Ключ2', значение2);data.append('Ключ3', значение3); синтаксис такой?

Comment: Если это вопрос, то да такой.

Comment: singlesly спасибо, за помощь, @Igor, просто был первее)